# Preventing XSS when using .attr('href', url) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss, code-injection

I want to update the `href` tag in jQuery. The data is untrusted. I'm trying to understand how can I craft a malicious input to cause an XSS type attack.

```
<a href='http://example.com' class='link'>Link</a>
```

My understanding is that the function below should terminate the `href` tag unexpectedly and create a new attribute `onclick`, but it doesn't work.

```
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('href',"' onclick='alert(\"ok\")'");    
});
```

Here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c1d7tuda/1/

P.S. End goal is to use [`_.escape()`](http://underscorejs.org/#escape) for HTML entities, but want to justify its usage.

Comment: Injecting in the way you're trying won't work unless your javascript builds a new anchor tag using a plain html string. For example. `$('<a href="' + userInput + '"></a>`

Comment: @KevinB Based on your comment, is it correct to assume that I don't need to worry about escaping HTML entities as long as I'm using `$.attr('href', '...')` to update anchor tag ?

Comment: As long as the value isn't used elsewhere where it would be vulnerable to such an attack.

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating the `href` attribute of your link using unvalidated user input, a malicious user could supply `javascript:alert(0)` as their `href` value. Then, if a user clicked on the link, it would execute the malicious user's arbitrary javascript.

Comment: You are correct although this is a different kind of attack. To mitigate it, I'd need to validate proper protocol in the url e.g. `http(s)`. I was trying to figure out the specific case where you can break out of the tag and create a new attribute.

Comment: Okay, you were just asking specifically about adding an `onclick` attribute through the `attr` method. I tried this attack strategy and was unable to add the `onclick` attribute to the anchor tag. However I would suggest as a general good practice to validate the user's input in some shape or form before doing anything with it. Use a positive validation approach: specify only which characters are allowed.